# How do subtraction between timestamp two rows per two with shift - Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I would like to make a subtraction with date_time in pandas python but with a shift of two rows, I don't know the function

```
Timestamp
2020-11-26 20:00:00
2020-11-26 21:00:00
2020-11-26 22:00:00
2020-11-26 23:30:00
```

Explanation:

```
(2020-11-26 21:00:00) - (2020-11-26 20:00:00)
(2020-11-26 23:30:00) - (2020-11-26 22:00:00)
```

The result must be:

```
01:00:00
01:30:00
```

Comment: `df["Timestamp"].diff().iloc[1::2]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want to iterate on chunks of two and find the difference, one approach is to:

```
res = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 2).diff().dropna()
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
        Timestamp
1 0 days 01:00:00
3 0 days 01:30:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to check if this is as type datetime.
If not, kindly do pd.to_datetime()

```
demo = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Timestamps'])
demotime = ['20:00:00','21:00:00','22:00:00','23:30:00']
demo['Timestamps'] = demotime
demo['Timestamps'] = pd.to_datetime(demo['Timestamps'])
```

Your dataframe would look like:

```
    Timestamps
0   2020-11-29 20:00:00
1   2020-11-29 21:00:00
2   2020-11-29 22:00:00
3   2020-11-29 23:30:00
```

After that you can either use for loop or while and in that just do:

```
demo.iloc[i+1,0]-demo.iloc[i,0]
```